# How to create Mysql test database in dockerized Rails application?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, docker, docker-compose

I managed to dockerize my existing Rails application running on a Mysql database. But I wonder if it is possible to setup docker-compose to create the test database in the same container?

Here is my docker-compose.yml and it wirks fine with the mysql for developing

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  db-data:

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.5
    restart: always
  ports:
    - "3307:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: verysecret
    MYSQL_USER: appdb
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    MYSQL_DATABASE: appdb
  volumes:
    - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000
    volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
  depends_on:
    - db
```

Can I add a darabase more in environment part somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create only one DB per Mysql container with docker compose. In your case, I think you should create a second DB container for the second database (isolated from the "real" DB, which is a good practice).
If you really want to have the 2 databases in the same container, you will have to create a Dockerfile based on the Mysql image, and add your command lines (RUN) to create the second DB.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but it won't necessarily be as a single container, but a manager for coupling containers. If this is okay, I've added some steps that will help you configure your project. **If not, I've added how to run a single image from a docker-compose file**

You will want to start off by creating a `docker-compose.yml` file in the source directory for your project.

Then you'll want to add something like this inside your yml file.(this was taken from Docker's quick-start documentation. Modified to show mysql instead of postgres)

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3306 -b '0.0.0.0'

volumes:
  - .:/myapp
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
depends_on:
  - db
```

Detail on how they create one can be found here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#define-the-project.

Things to note:

- `web` is the details about the rails container. So you will want to add an `image` property if you have already created your rails image.
- Also, `build: .` is expecting your Dockerfile to be in the same location as your project. So if you create this docker-compose.yml somewhere else, you'll have to provide the path.
- `depends_on` allows your app to build the DB before running rails

Once you finished creating the `docker-compose.yml` file run:
`docker-compose build`
followed by:
`docker-compose up`

If separating the containers, isn't what you are looking for: then you might want to look into creating a single image running both applications. Then use something like this to run from docker-compose.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: {your-app-image}
    build: .
volumes:
  - .:/myapp
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
  - "3306:3306"
```

Note: somethings might vary on how you create your image from the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Thanks but as stated it already works with my docker and docker-compose. The question is if i can have compose to create to databases ob the same container

Comment: Np. I sort of referenced how you could solve that issue. I think if you're trying to create the entire app inside one container, you might want to try adding more layers in your Dockerfile to include the MySQL app, and dependencies - then expose the additional port. I don't know if you can merge containers directly from docker-compose. Maybe someone can answer it and teach us both.